# npm install SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 163836 (bluebird)

Tags: json, node.js

When I do `npm install` I get this error:

```
Unexpected token u in JSON at position 163836
```

This is the log:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'install' ]
2 info using npm@5.0.3
3 info using node@v8.1.3
4 verbose npm-session c0d8f22cf8f053a1
5 silly install runPreinstallTopLevelLifecycles
6 silly preinstall bitcointrackerserver@1.0.0
7 info lifecycle bitcointrackerserver@1.0.0~preinstall: bitcointrackerserver@1.0.0
8 silly lifecycle bitcointrackerserver@1.0.0~preinstall: no script for preinstall, continuing
9 silly install loadCurrentTree
10 silly install readLocalPackageData
11 silly install loadIdealTree
12 silly install cloneCurrentTreeToIdealTree
13 silly install loadShrinkwrap
14 verbose stack SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 163836
14 verbose stack     at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
14 verbose stack     at module.exports (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\parse-json.js:3:15)
14 verbose stack     at BB.join (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\install\read-shrinkwrap.js:31:20)
14 verbose stack     at tryCatcher (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\util.js:16:23)
14 verbose stack     at Holder$3._callFunction (eval at generateHolderClass (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\join.js:92:16), <anonymous>:14:44)
14 verbose stack     at Holder$3.checkFulfillment (eval at generateHolderClass (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\join.js:92:16), <anonymous>:29:30)
14 verbose stack     at Promise.eval (eval at thenCallback (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\join.js:14:16), <anonymous>:6:20)
14 verbose stack     at Promise._settlePromise (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:566:21)
14 verbose stack     at Promise._settlePromise0 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:614:10)
14 verbose stack     at Promise._settlePromises (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:693:18)
14 verbose stack     at Promise._fulfill (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:638:18)
14 verbose stack     at Promise._settlePromise (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:582:21)
14 verbose stack     at Promise._settlePromise0 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:614:10)
14 verbose stack     at Promise._settlePromises (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:693:18)
14 verbose stack     at Promise._fulfill (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:638:18)
14 verbose stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\nodeback.js:42:21
15 verbose cwd D:\Projects\xampp\htdocs\bitcointrackerserver_updated
16 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.15063
17 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"
18 verbose node v8.1.3
19 verbose npm  v5.0.3
20 error Unexpected token u in JSON at position 163836
21 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Package.json:

```
{
      "name": "bitcointrackerserver",
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "description": "Using latest JavaScript features on the server",
      "repository": {
        "type": "git",
        "url": "git+https://github.com/vmasto/express-babel.git"
      },
      "author": "Vassilis Mastorostergios <vmasto@gmail.com>",
      "license": "MIT",
      "main": "dist/index.js",
      "engines": {
        "node": "~6.9.1",
        "npm": ">=3.10.0"
      },
      "scripts": {
        "prestart": "npm run -s build",
        "start": "node dist/index.js",
        "dev": "nodemon src/index.js --exec \"node -r dotenv/config -r babel-register\"",
        "clean": "rimraf dist",
        "build": "npm run clean && mkdir -p dist && babel src -s -D -d dist",
        "test": "jest --watch",
        "lint": "esw -w src test"
      },
      "keywords": [
        "express",
        "babel",
        "boilerplate",
        "scaffold",
        "es6",
        "es2015",
        "es2016",
        "es2017",
        "jest",
        "eslint"
      ],
      "dependencies": {
        "axios": "^0.16.2",
        "babel-cli": "^6.24.1",
        "babel-preset-env": "^1.4.0",
        "bluebird": "^3.5.0",
        "body-parser": "^1.17.1",
        "check-proxy": "^0.1.3",
        "express": "^4.15.2",
        "https-proxy-agent": "^2.0.0",
        "morgan": "^1.7.0",
        "pug": "^2.0.0-beta11",
        "request": "^2.81.0",
        "rimraf": "^2.6.1"
      },
      "devDependencies": {
        "babel-jest": "^20.0.0",
        "babel-register": "^6.24.1",
        "dotenv": "^4.0.0",
        "eslint": "^3.19.0",
        "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.2.0",
        "eslint-plugin-jest": "^20.0.0",
        "eslint-watch": "^3.1.0",
        "jest": "^20.0.0",
        "nodemon": "^1.11.0",
        "supertest": "^3.0.0"
      },
      "babel": {
        "presets": [
          [
            "env",
            {
              "targets": {
                "node": "current"
              }
            }
          ]
        ]
      },
      "eslintConfig": {
        "plugins": [
          "import",
          "jest"
        ],
        "parserOptions": {
          "ecmaVersion": 2017,
          "sourceType": "module"
        },
        "env": {
          "node": true,
          "jest": true
        },
        "extends": [
          "eslint:recommended"
        ],
        "rules": {
          "jest/no-focused-tests": 2,
          "jest/no-identical-title": 2
        }
      },
      "jest": {
        "testEnvironment": "node"
      },
      "bugs": {
        "url": "https://github.com/vmasto/express-babel/issues"
      },
      "homepage": "https://github.com/vmasto/express-babel#readme",
      "directories": {
        "test": "test"
      }
    }
```

I cant find anything how to fix it, I tried to reinstall NodeJS but it didn't work. Also tried to clear the cache.

Anyone an idea why and how to fix? because I didn't wrote that code obviously

Comment: Can you share your package.json file?

Comment: Yeah! Thats my project package.json not from the nodejs folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your version of **node v8.1.3** and **npm v5.0.3**, does not support a dependency in **package.json**. I have checked with **npm 4.1.2** and **node v6.9.3** and it installs perfectly with node v6.9.3 and npm 4.1.2.

So my suggestion is for you to use **nvm** to change the node version.

```
nvm install 6.9.3
nvm use v6.9.3
```

To change the node version to supported version.

Update me on how it goes;

Good Luck;

Comment: Thank you. I'm installing a linux server now because I will deploy everything on a linux server. When that's done I try this. thank you very much.

Comment: Your wellcome :D, glad that I could help you :D